# Parsing Nested JSON within Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, nest

I am trying to parse nested JSON from the VirusTotal API but when ran it comes back as this error, I tried a different method found in https://app.quicktype.io/ but it came back as NULL and I couldn't get that working either

```
 Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMa
p<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Data'
```

My code is below, I am parsing 2 APIs and one is working so ignore the other one, if possible I would like to do this without completely rewriting my program as time is thin.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = "https://urlhaus-api.abuse.ch/v1/urls/recent/"; //address for URL file




Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key:key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: "Gone Smishin'",
      home:  GoneSmishin(),
    );
  }
}

class GoneSmishin extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoneSmishin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  State<GoneSmishin> createState() {
    return _GoneSmishinState();
  }
}

class Data {
  late Attributes attributes;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "attributes": attributes.toJson(),
  };
}
class Attributes {
  late LastAnalysisStats lastAnalysisStats;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "last_analysis_stats": lastAnalysisStats.toJson(),
  };
}
class LastAnalysisStats {
  static late int malicious;
  static late int suspicious;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "malicious": malicious,
    "suspicious": suspicious,
  };
}


class _GoneSmishinState extends State<GoneSmishin> {

  late Data data;

  String message = "";
  String word = "";
  bool isOn = false;

  final myController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  var attributes = '';

  String urlHaus = "URLHaus";
  String virusTotal = "VirusTotal";
  String list = "Whitelist";


  urlHausParseBox() async {
    String url = myController.text;
    var urlEncoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(myController.text));
    var urlNoPadding = urlEncoded.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'='), '');

    final response2 = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls/$urlNoPadding"),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-apikey': '11111111111111111111111111111111111111'
      },
    );

    print(urlEncoded);
    print(response2.body);
    if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        final decoded = json.decode(response2.body);
        data = decoded['data'];
      });
    }
    if (((LastAnalysisStats.suspicious) + (LastAnalysisStats.malicious)) >= 2) {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Found in VirusTotal - Possibly Malicious';
      });
    } else if (((LastAnalysisStats.suspicious) + (LastAnalysisStats.malicious)) <= 1) {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Found in VirusTotal - Probably not Malicious';
        print((LastAnalysisStats.suspicious) + (LastAnalysisStats.malicious));
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        virusTotal = 'Not found in VirusTotal';
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class VirusTotal {
  final _url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls';
  final apiKey = '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  Future<void> getUrlAnalysisReport(String url) async {
    var urlEncoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(url));
    var urlId = urlEncoded.replaceAll(RegExp(r'='), '');
    var response = await HttpReqService.get<JMap>(
      '$_url/$urlId', 
      jsonResponse: true,
      auth: AuthType.apiKey,
      authData: MapEntry('x-apikey', apiKey),
    );
    
    print(response?['data']['attributes'].keys.toList());
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await VirusTotal().getUrlAnalysisReport('https://www.edx.org');
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Output:

```
[last_modification_date, last_http_response_cookies, times_submitted, total_votes, title, last_submission_date, last_http_response_content_length, last_http_response_headers, reputation, threat_names, tags, last_analysis_date, first_submission_date, categories, last_http_response_content_sha256, last_http_response_code, last_final_url, trackers, url, last_analysis_stats, last_analysis_results, html_meta, outgoing_links]

Job done!
```

You need to create your classes according to 'attributes' map, you can use this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io).